# Showing results by date from several MySQL tables

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have few tables for different kind of post but would like to show them in one feed. I order table data by date and than display it using `fetchColumn`. How can I add one table to another, so that posts from both tables would be integrated by date and fetched by order all together?

```
  $type_select_query= $dbh -> prepare("SELECT type FROM first post WHERE id = :id   ORDER BY date DESC");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using `UNION`:

```
(SELECT ... FROM t1 WHERE ...)
 UNION
(SELECT ... FROM t2 WHERE ...)
ORDER BY ...;
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/union.html